# Data type for an array of Object in realm - react-native realm

Tags: react-native, realm, mongodb-realm

I'm using realm for Javascript using React-native

I want to generate a realm schema to hold an array of Object as this:

```
arrayOfObj:[{ key1:1111, key2:2222, key3:333 }]
```

What I have tried so far is using the *mixed* type in my schema

```
const mySchema = {
    name: "mySchema",
    properties: {
        _id: "objectId",
        arrOfObj: "mixed" //'have used mixed[] too but they all don't work
    }
}
```

I have tried using *mixed* and also using *mixed[]* but when I try to insert the array of object i get the error: mySchema.arrOfObj must be of type 'mixed?[]', got 'object' ([object Object])].

Now, What is the correct data type for the array of object in realm?

Comment: Mixed types seems to be still in beta https://github.com/realm/realm-js/releases/tag/v10.5.0-beta.1

Comment: Do you wanna store any data in the array or do you know the structure of the data ?

Comment: @MichaelBahl I want to store **One object in an array with key-value pair of ObjectId: Integer**, something like this `[ {'60b6c1381d5d2f2afe4b3b' : 2, '51b6c15a1d7d6a2ba99a6c' : 3} ]`

Comment: @MichaelBahl can you provide some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const myScheme = {
  name: "myScheme",
  primaryKey: "_id",
  properties: {
   _id: "objectId",
   _partition: "string",
   name: "string",
   tasks: "myData[]"
 }
};

const myData = {
  name: "myData",
  primaryKey: "_id",
  properties: {
    _id: "objectId",
    _partition: "string",
    firstname: "string",
    lastname: "string",
 }
```

};

Comment: This will create a separate `myData` physical objects, how to make it save inside `myScheme`?